# Creating Text Editior in Django

Tags: django, markdown, editor

I want to create a notes app in django and want a text editor which helps user to add bullets and bold text and more functionalities. How can i do this in the template in django?
I am a newbie in django so please suggest me some ways to do that.

Comment: Django already has a package named `django-ckeditor` which is likely sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either _ or * around a word to make it italic, or __ or ** around a word to make it bold. You can also use common keyboard shortcuts, including CTRL/CMD + B to bold, and CTRL/CMD + I to italicize.

```
*italics* (or _italics_) renders as italics
**bold** renders as bold
***bold-italic*** renders as Bold Italics
~~strikethrough~~ renders as Strike Through
```

Comment: But that will not be a good idea if user has do it.

Comment: I want something like what we see when we are writing a question in stackoverflow.

Comment: You can  also use it as a feature .

Comment: You can call if and else statement in these like :-  if  user clicks bold , then use **bold* function